# How to use getHour() to get current hour in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
fun getHours() = int
    val openHours = 7
    val now = getHours()
    val office: String
    office = if (now > 7){
        "Office already open"
    } else if(now == openHours){
        "wait a minute, office will be open"
    }else{
        "office is closed"
    }
    println(office)
```

The following code doesn't seem to get me the current hour from my computer, what am I missing?

Comment: Does this code get you any output or return value or does it just not run?

Answer (score 4):

[The right syntax of defining a function in Kotlin would be](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html):

```
// function without params and returns Unit
fun functionName1() {} 

// function with one parameter and returns Int
fun functionName2(text: String): Int {
    return 6
} 

// short syntax for one line function with two params and Boolean as return value
fun functionName3(text: String, isVisible: Boolean): Boolean = text.isEmpty && isVisible
```

Code provided by you has incorrect syntax, please fix it. It should be something like this:

```
fun getHours(): String {
    val openHours = 7
    val now = getCurrentHour()
    val office = when {
        now > 7 -> "Office already open"
        now == openHours -> "wait a minute, office will be open"
        else -> "office is closed"
    }
    println(office)
    return office
}

fun getCurrentHour(): Int {
    // somehow get current hour, for example using java.util.Calendar class
    return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current system time using LocalDateTime class like :

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
val currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
```

And to get hours specifically you could use DateTimeFormatter class like:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
currentDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the answer given by @Sergey is correct.

Just one minor nit:
I would not use `java.util.Date` for it but one of the classes from `java.time`, see this example:

```
fun getHours(): String {
    val openHours = 7
    val now = java.time.ZonedDateTime.now(java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault()).hour
    val office = when {
        now > 7             -> "Office already open"
        now == openHours    -> "wait a minute, office will be open"
        else                -> "office is closed"
    }
    return office
}
```

using that in a `fun main()` like

```
fun main() {
    println(getHours())
}
```

would then result in the (system dependent) output

```
office is closed
```

on my system at 08:48 o'clock in UTC+2.